# Symlink in Laravel current release folder from external folder

Tags: laravel, symlink

I am using zero downtime deployment for Laravel and I have a folder which is updated regularly with weather files.

The folder structure is like:
releases/1 - where the current release is.
current/ - linked to /releases/1 and this is where Apache server root is.
public/weather - this is the folder where weather files are stored (via ftp process).

Can I use symlink on public/weather -> /current/public/weather?

Command I try to use:
ln -nfs --relative /var/www/html/public/weather /var/www/html/current/public/weather
the command appears to work, however I can not see it linked with ls -al.

If I try:
ln /var/www/html/public/weather /var/www/html/current/public/weather
I get this error.
ln: /var/www/html/public/wdisplay: hard link not allowed for directory

Thank you